# width is not being consistent

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have a problem trying to make the labels (purple box where name, quantity sold and gross sales are written, not including the input field) to be the same width. Currently, as the picture below, the label box is slightly larger for the field that is only one in one row, compare to the ones that are half size below.

[how it looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dud5f.png)

I tried w-44 (178 rem) in tailwind, manually styling in pixel as well, still no clue.

When width is below 60px, it seems to become even. The larger pixel I put in make the differences even bigger.

Thank you in advance!

```
      <div className="px-2 pt-4 sm:px-12 sm:pt-4">
        <div className="font-semibold text-2xl pb-8">Category Details</div>
        <div className="flex flex-wrap gap-6">
          <div className="flex-grow w-full">
            <div className="form-control">
              <label className="input-group">
                <span
                  className={`w-[180px] text-sm bg-opacity-40`}>
                  Name
                </span>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="input input-bordered w-full"
                  value={sale?.category_name}
                  readOnly={true}
                />
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="flex-grow">
            <div className="form-control w-full">
              <label className="input-group">
                <span
                  className={`w-[180px] text-sm bg-opacity-40`}>
                  Quantity Sold
                </span>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="input input-bordered w-full"
                  value={sale?.quantity}
                  readOnly={true}
                />
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="flex-grow">
            <div className="form-control w-full">
              <label className="input-group">
                <span
                  className={`w-[180px] text-sm bg-opacity-40`}>
                  Gross Sales
                </span>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="input input-bordered w-full"
                  value={sale?.gross_sales}
                  readOnly={true}
                />
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: Is there any other CSS other than Tailwind? I can see non-Tailwind classes like `form-control`, `input`, `input-bordered`, etc.